# Exact computation of n choose k

Tags: numerical-methods

For what n>=1 can the binomial coefficient "n choose k" be computed exactly in IEEE double precision arithmetic? For what n>=1 will intermediate factorials overflow?

Comment: Which intermediate factorials are involved depends on which formula you use to compute the thing.

Comment: let's say i use n!/k!(n-k)! Then n! will dictate the overflow

Comment: however, what is the first part of the question asking?

Comment: What does the "EXACTLY" mean here?

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be possible up to and including $n = 54$. Compute the binomial coefficient as:
$$
\binom{n}{k} =
\frac{n\cdot(n - 1)\cdots (n - k + 1)}{1\cdot 2\cdots k}
= \bigg(\bigg(\bigg(1\cdot\frac{n}{1}\bigg)\cdot\frac{n - 1}{2}\bigg)\cdots \frac{n - k + 1}{k}\bigg)
$$
That way there will always be enough prime factors in the product that the divisions are exact (have no non-zero remainders).

(NB. Multiply first, then divide. For example, it cannot be said beforehand which of $n$ and $n-1$ is divisible by $2$, but one of them has to be. And so on.)

---

Computed as above, with floating point numbers and with arbitrary precision integers, the exact results look like this (floating point representation indicated by a decimal point):
$$
\binom{54}{26} = \binom{54}{28} = 1877405874732108.0 = 1877405874732108
$$
The largest value for $n = 54$ is still the same integer in both arithmetics:
$$
\binom{54}{27} = \binom{54}{27} = 1946939425648112.0 = 1946939425648112
$$
For $n = 55$ at least some floating point results are only approximations and may not even be integers:
$$
\binom{55}{27} \approx 3824345300380219.5 \ne 3824345300380220 = \binom{55}{27}
$$
As larger binomial coefficients require more and more digits, floating point representation becomes increasingly inaccurate.

Comment: Reasonable since $\binom{2n}{n}\sim 2^{2n}$, and thus the $1+53$ bits of mantissa get used up or maxed out by $2n=54$.

Comment: Would the order of operation matter?  Would (n/k)(n-1/k-1)....(n-k+1) or (n-k-1)(n-k+2/2)....(n/k) yield different results? What if you did some weird thing like calculate (n-k)(n-k+1)... until you get close to an overflow and the divide by 1\*2*... until you stop having integer results then continue multiplying the top until it gets close to being to big and then you divide for a while and keep "trading off".

Comment: @fleablood, I think you'll see that the order matters if you just try some simple examples.

Comment: I'm not a programmer (at least not for anything where this would be a concern) so no I don't really know if order matters.  I see that if we were trying 14C8 for example and we start 13/7*11/3* etc. that'd be a bad choice whereas 14/7*12/6*10/5 etc. would be better.  But i'm not sure (n/1)(n-1/2) is the best choice either.  If precision was, say, 3 decimal places, I think both (n/1)(n-1/2)... and (n/8)(n-1/7) would both have issues but 8*9div(1*2*3*4)*10div(5*6)*11div7*12*13div8*14 would be better but 14div(7*2)*12div(3*4)*10div5*9div6*8*11*13 is best.

Comment: @fleablood, I see. Yes, I suppose there might be different orders that are in some sense better. I just don't know how to define one beforehand. The order I showed is simple and guarantees that the intermediate results are integers (until the product overflows).

Comment: @JussiPiitulainen: I doubt it makes much difference, but don't you want to do the multiplications in ascending order as well?

Comment: Hmm. I suppose that while doing the multiplications in ascending order keeps some of the earlier results smaller, it doesn't make any difference to what the largest intermediate result is, since that involves the whole numerator anyway, so it doesn't help.